# Lua Error: attempt to compare __lt on function and number

Tags: lua

Im trying to compare values on lua like this code above:

```
if (self.areaTextoVisible:measureText(linhas[linhaIndice] .. " " .. w) < (self.areaTextoVisibleWidth - (offSetScroll + self.margemLateral + (self.margens * 2)))) then               
linhas[linhaIndice] = linhas[linhaIndice] .. " " .. w;
```

but I get the "attempt to compare __lt on function and number". How can i solve this problem?

Comment: It means `(self.areaTextoVisible:measureText(linhas[linhaIndice] .. " " .. w)` is a function

Comment: Yes. But this function return a value(number).

Comment: We need to know what `measureText` is returning. Or more to the point, we need to *see* `measureText`.

Comment: Actually measureText is a function from lua canvas module and is returning a multiple result with the dimensions(with,height) from text.